# I'm trying to install ubuntu from a USB stick but after restarting after installation is complete it asks me to install again

Tags: system-installation

Title basically. I keep trying to install Ubuntu from the USB stick. After installation, I reboot like it says. However it keeps starting the installation process again.

Comment: Is your computer booting back to the USB instead of the hard drive?

Comment: I think your supposed to remove the usb after installation is complete...

Answer (score 0):

When installation is complete and the computer reboots remove the usb drive so that the computer reboots off the hard drive rather than the USB drive.